# classList.toggle doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I have noticed that toggling class in Firefox is not working and I'm not sure why.

```
var contactUs = document.querySelectorAll('.contact-us')[0];

var buttonExpand = document.querySelectorAll('a.write')[0];
buttonExpand.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    contactUs.classList.toggle('js-expand-form');
    console.log('click');
},false);
```

When I click on `a.write` in Firefox nothing happens. It works on Chrome and IE.
The problem is related both to event binding and to `classList.toggle`, because `console.log('click')` doesn't work in FF and when I type manually from console:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.contact-us')[0].classList.toggle('js-expand-form')
```

it returns true or false but nothing actually changes - inspected element doesn't get a new class. 
What concerns me even more is that the same line pasted in Chrome's console doesn't take effect either, despite the fact it works in normal circumstances.
jQuery's equivalent `jQuery('.contact-us').toggleClass('js-expand-form')` works in every browser, including pasting into console.

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3t7pbv/4/).

Comment: General hint: If you want just one item, use `querySelector()` instead of `querySelectorAll()`

Comment: It works for me. There is probably something else wrong with the code. Can you create a fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: @light http://jsfiddle.net/Lh3t7pbv/4/ - what is strange is that js and jQuery code works in this fiddle, but when I run my website on Firefox with the same code only jQuery version is executed on click event. Any ideas what could be the reason?

Comment: **Problem solved.**  The reason was that I executed this code in `window.onload`, when I moved it elsewhere it started to work in Firefox.

Comment: @van_folmert please answer and accept your question then, so it will be clear to others from question list that the problem is solved. Maybe someday someone with the same issue will run into it and it could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved. The problem was caused by including code in `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
var buttonExpand = document.querySelectorAll('a.write')[0];
buttonExpand.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('click');
},false);
}
```

It started to work in Firefox after moving it elsewhere:

```
var buttonExpand = document.querySelectorAll('a.write')[0];
buttonExpand.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    console.log('click');
},false);

window.onload = function() {
}
```

Not sure **why** Firefox had problem with that, though.

Comment: Perhaps you had some very slow-loading stuff in the page so onload had not actually fired when you tested?

Answer (score 2):

You change the class on link (`a.write`). I'd guess that the link fires, page reloads and changes are flushed away.

Try to add

```
e.preventDefault();
```

in the handler after the `toggle()` command.

Comment: yeah I've forgotten about `e.preventDefault();` but it doesn't solve this particular issue with my website being run on Firefox